# color code based on presence/absence of factor in a list with ggplot

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2, color-codes

I have some genomic data that consists of various statistics ("BHTD", "BHNS") calculated for each gene. There is also a column ("func.cat") containing functional classification for each of the genes; these categories are not mutually exclusive and are represented by the numbers 1-34, ie. a gene may belong to multiple functional categories such as 1,5, and 7. I am trying to write some code that will allow me to explore where the genes in each functional category land in the distribution of the whole dataset. The problem I am having pertains to how to iterate over the list in the $func.cat column (the functional classifications which are labeled as 1-34 separated by ",").

What I have tried so far is this:

```
library(ggplot2)

dat$cat <- with(dat, factor(ifelse(func.cat == "4", 1, 0)))
```

(note I would change the "4" depending on which category I wish to look at)

I realize that "==" is causing my problem as something with "1,4,5" will not equal 4, but I am not sure how to iterate over the items in that list - this is the root of my problem.

```
p1 <- ggplot(dat, aes(x=BHNS, y=BHTD)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = cat))
p1
```

This produces a plot that will highlight all the dots corresponding to genes classified as category 4, but only category 4. What I desire is to have any gene that has been classified as category 4 to be colored, regardless of whether it has also been classified as another category.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions!

Here is a subset of the data:

> dput(dat)
>   structure(list(BHTD = c(-2.407361658, -1.796755011, -2.033328407, 
>   -1.999300651, -1.705683372, -2.07316744, -2.14888815, -1.238415232, 
>   -1.964081372, -0.946236, -1.804456645, -1.117478076, -0.865610729, 
>   -2.014708065, -1.700170785, -2.066551154, -2.321719704, -1.382856082, 
>   -1.860020378, -1.938464139, -1.772410788, -1.98276263, -1.474897562, 
>   -2.341638838, -1.477241173, -1.997347068, -0.951587062, -1.472879561, 
>   -2.205905395, -1.573116753, NA, -1.793176812, -1.508295823, -1.411124368, 
>   -1.659159007, NA, -2.184113573, -1.753603939, -0.946572775, -2.230161692, 
>   -2.257687027, -2.052893551, -1.684633689, -1.723560773, -1.311466597, 
>   -0.878316233, -1.760067015, -0.991159868, -1.597358958, -1.68808286, 
>   -2.24992473, -1.384269004, -1.245007137, -0.733919882, -0.951587062, 
>   -1.716349956, -1.857569436, -2.03690476, -1.742918492, -1.652319766, 
>   -1.018325037, -1.237294825, -1.705582368, -2.251182699, -1.44607638, 
>   -1.86373038, -1.238915153, -1.999390778, -2.258813941, -2.307483301, 
>   -1.824001963, -2.046894346, -1.973018785, -1.822540934, -2.098850332, 
>   -1.622573473, -1.385826692, -0.13581749, -1.473072964, -1.912742974, 
>   -1.331192083, -1.35995547, -1.414638574, -2.3080906, -1.928952143, 
>   -1.73843242, -1.78263942, -2.045782556, -1.83695726, -1.782816678, 
>   -1.384301082, -1.738544771, -2.122562601, -1.008751008, NA, 0.210106499, 
>   NA, -1.497540674, -1.175421047, -2.077668436, 0, -2.392002104, 
>   -2.172277005, -2.248237481, -1.754777666, -1.205907566, -2.157860036, 
>   -2.372725867, -1.776418131, NA, -1.981646655, -1.83215468, -1.632970565, 
>   -1.796441664, -1.16749959, -2.097760427, -1.688111791, -1.091669998, 
>   -2.031922436, -1.609781944, -1.701092173, -1.741641383, -1.648047931, 
>   0, NA, -2.155091718, -2.19686492, -2.043064889, -1.900228157, 
>   -1.033211891, -1.741600124, -1.952787018, -1.635681652, -1.414146075, 
>   -1.59652266, -0.67250785, -1.741490676, -1.668132969, -1.547999618, 
>   -2.096369244, -1.585198776, -0.893064463, -1.720571973, -2.22165509, 
>   -0.87006502, -2.026357729, -1.903054158, -2.336779135, -1.804456645, 
>   -2.187397942, -1.738544771, NA, NA, -2.244769328, -1.443026239, 
>   -2.1075961, -1.284505684, -2.171199234, 0, -1.832601732, NA, 
>   NA, -1.92361227, -1.404739557, -1.673782332, -1.630260976, -1.949121617, 
>   -1.535783949, -0.93437506, -1.682586839, -1.211290477, -1.837644381, 
>   -2.006840092, -2.094965703, -1.501569366, -1.686096428, -1.766893171, 
>   -1.025055976, -1.445292041, -1.804456645, -1.295447345, -2.333513471, 
>   -2.024633218, -1.945932896, -2.138973359, -1.192594283, -1.032891761, 
>   -2.274612038, -1.572404387, -1.157314923, -1.821517283, -0.951587062, 
>   -1.491063082, -1.262268477, -1.285825224, -2.125036752, -2.254193395, 
>   -2.025063005, -1.781927799, -1.817341356, -2.363964155, -1.324016132, 
>   -1.807867509, -1.28536312, -2.304611837, -1.805333968, -1.981011267, 
>   -1.148360279, -2.254965576, -1.832997391, -1.284505684, -1.36694829, 
>   -1.511236509, -2.199333133, -2.162070519, -1.613952632, -1.98074573, 
>   -1.937973938, -1.775626812, -1.110822415, -2.350956471, -0.798852174, 
>   -1.570167789, -1.205143435, -1.227387321, -1.870071641, -1.804119234, 
>   -1.852186861, -1.980559594, -1.910654458, -1.846696172, -0.851873121, 
>   -2.093777922, -2.009089876, -1.341030926, -1.714790638, -2.035487818, 
>   -1.655358562, -1.24566631, -2.268812805, -2.033792651, -1.964347513, 
>   -1.177587982, -1.014825692, -1.543347759, -1.982771035, -2.095046073, 
>   -2.396210518, -1.190624287, -1.980840471, -1.629812596, -2.075443039, 
>   -1.117986711, -1.284505684, -1.737984295, -1.909068715, -1.44607638, 
>   -0.13581749, -2.26199378, NA, -1.13387384, -1.775626812, -1.796501476, 
>   -1.98917241, -1.980551021, -1.804456645, -2.030319284, -1.450348529, 
>   -2.094406662, -2.473686253, -2.076634731, -1.507574766, -1.964339138, 
>   -1.459205458, -2.408551092, -2.150651491, -2.058411824, -2.073951488, 
>   -1.674678062, -2.066920278, -2.322477648, NA, NA, NA, -2.066255854, 
>   -1.589735284, -1.607268225, -2.548035167, NA, NA, -0.951587062, 
>   -1.700335988, -2.189638552, -1.659055578, -2.205270213, -1.472855439, 
>   -1.785739256, -1.627265507, -1.910645503, -2.050893789, NA, -0.062843564, 
>   -0.673444373, -1.091002703, -1.326825703, -1.050001441, -1.891635725, 
>   NA, NA, -1.494850186, -1.156519132, -1.999300651, -0.092286396, 
>   -0.183330333, -1.845843023, -1.640896562, -1.572404387, -1.860224553, 
>   -1.648638668, -1.872150192, -2.245024819, -1.737840368, -1.385826692, 
>   -1.981735368, -1.284505684, -2.14125006, -1.804456645, -0.973371896, 
>   -0.314443643, -1.715455449, -1.551622633, -1.673782332, -1.467606151, 
>   -1.910546588, -1.275308274, -1.78203764, -0.835133, -0.951587062, 
>   NA, NA, -1.467647481, -2.351522017, -1.63428397, -1.355853241, 
>   -2.110040041, -1.960573835, -2.230550217, -1.919743893, -1.064911257, 
>   -1.999122333, -1.717022526, -1.284505684, -2.195620712, -1.678699875, 
>   -0.951587062, -0.985647431, -1.760291205, NA, NA, -1.980847743, 
>   -1.546669986, -1.571405894, -1.210776173, -0.981913114, -1.507574766, 
>   -1.736694039, -1.540253602, -1.407640256, -1.697004898, -1.425404963, 
>   -0.952113105, -1.504651095, -0.664885437, -0.988878576, -1.963728301, 
>   -1.873625986, -2.375331349, -0.951587062, -1.714055933, -1.835483999, 
>   0.531735976, -1.247617445, -1.597358958, -0.870980998, -1.910955616, 
>   -1.472767466, -1.909412827, -1.989851075, -1.928950806, -2.125207581, 
>   -0.702179857, NA, -1.258758453, -0.951587062, -1.910744418, -1.977408625, 
>   -2.185569218, -1.649306639, -1.67542209, -1.859870782, -1.688905215, 
>   -1.014897763, -2.098942661, -1.50114744, -1.507574766, -2.401004247, 
>   -1.630373071, -1.704144046, -2.341487878, -1.648352839, -1.449448077, 
>   -1.568042202, -1.056046556, -1.955734929, -1.326772791, -1.125210141, 
>   -1.263721543, -1.787741424, -1.631502453, -1.507574766, -1.832997391, 
>   -2.074270271, -1.720214873, -1.832601732, -1.981646655, -1.538923716, 
>   -2.074197994, -1.804456645, -2.219273959, -1.630260976, -2.095269031, 
>   -1.058597445, -1.103308726, -0.222433651, 0.363131214, -1.316124286, 
>   -1.428135774, -1.13088371, -2.237049349, -1.212032461, -1.651632249, 
>   -1.321079056, -2.058330473, -1.908682716, -1.285163648, NA, -2.033320494, 
>   -1.561765422, -0.650534061, -1.54891411, -1.775629164, -1.16720697, 
>   -1.67466461, -2.11038659, -1.622183558, -0.805494207, NA, -1.284505684, 
>   -1.629812596, 0, -1.733554458, -1.471842151, -2.325564799, -1.931011616, 
>   -0.951587062, -1.674650606, -2.084007693, -0.13581749, -0.728334229, 
>   -0.697339499, -1.717022526, -1.84336553, -2.102771894, -1.613099192, 
>   -1.373005006, -1.404053215, -1.563983261, -1.240665527, -1.169474104, 
>   -0.499894742, -1.477392537, 0, -1.35617011, -1.552690092, -1.266997489, 
>   -1.800049126, -1.284505684, -1.738096391, -1.081560759, -0.353725082, 
>   -1.833482909, -1.820326999, -1.929571801, -1.445764205, -1.507261023, 
>   -1.029306695, -1.507418679, -1.28536312, -1.888950799, -0.925858686
>   ), BHNS = c(-0.536445534500279, -2.51590975211276, 0.975176838838268, 
>   1.16762127648105, 0.306137539516978, -1.74214520673759, -1.64717485268251, 
>   -3.95922066144353, -3.39635293660797, -0.970330946311565, 0.172619995428375, 
>   2.48298883472192, 0.793974082613881, 0.501039140250149, 0.804337655982506, 
>   -3.30714604156556, -1.20707193264363, 2.45797739273923, -1.59701672552781, 
>   -1.66914695085005, 0.0674012955390476, 1.62417842412305, -2.58203639235661, 
>   -2.12135486007817, NA, 1.90106289648472, NA, -4.03524619467747, 
>   -1.22854600858282, -1.07477486644834, NA, -2.28606696929486, 
>   -2.66907956622894, -2.72803842459239, 1.85426238301574, NA, -1.21282898286863, 
>   NA, 2.2855102029862, 0.277515630354603, -2.22927291562984, -0.408924692322956, 
>   1.28800115719665, -3.38950127542429, 0.674326255003232, 0.100856586743738, 
>   -1.09361761185504, 4.48642120653207, NA, -0.778285568839945, 
>   -1.61559599922626, 1.11437504404848, NA, 2.36961492996114, NA, 
>   -3.31657121257007, -1.26574933393628, -1.65527597153758, -1.43219956248087, 
>   -4.48337471597694, -0.38392378868904, 2.18997939435775, -1.45440502892558, 
>   -0.498677781445362, NA, 0.263936976427928, 2.13996790558608, 
>   2.02108542548667, 2.04917825749504, 0.0491580369030717, 3.50533020548612, 
>   0.691750405572648, -2.95240608774007, -3.02575598315416, -0.8637227975704, 
>   0.759542644984083, -0.144270618649459, NA, -0.357833850766232, 
>   -2.35061857677948, 0.846721856058998, -4.30457112149904, NA, 
>   0.521384795227345, -2.68755642840854, 0.301655700405515, -2.73328355695093, 
>   1.81192054331534, -2.93795656056712, -4.54923476572377, -0.0705314386206745, 
>   1.33535189698769, -0.814805548174206, 1.37244958099412, 1.06210539305522, 
>   -0.31272164063358, NA, NA, NA, -0.974460560578356, NA, -1.09691503978493, 
>   -1.16129610027415, 0.807081820419685, 0.219769515667387, NA, 
>   -2.11671131861236, -0.00825953442660159, -3.34135267869532, NA, 
>   -2.14077271733041, -1.53984154690997, -2.55464025816218, 1.87699362206363, 
>   NA, 1.21608554754864, 2.37418777663669, 2.55877670413167, 0.802426328525387, 
>   -2.46322401518915, -2.68656498120426, -1.82904543820427, NA, 
>   NA, NA, -2.60297624909947, -3.67353291535057, -0.495574112777514, 
>   2.03017007695609, -0.0124338742030449, 1.12209795456402, NA, 
>   0.866863701855014, 3.7209135742554, 0.375208084011011, -1.45849683298558, 
>   -0.19123665984119, -0.188018140361373, 1.19734815284619, 0.00853725978565168, 
>   -0.730240497597164, NA, -4.96375079708713, 1.19107712360479, 
>   -0.633787160803514, 0.499368742064575, 0.664122184333449, -0.103947741244196, 
>   -2.14739584713273, 1.74822462363828, 1.32687851322831, NA, NA, 
>   -0.616579186144451, -4.44411553936161, -2.84734557522817, -1.54029271130266, 
>   -0.292331969757492, NA, -1.66741119163565, NA, NA, -4.34294861371069, 
>   NA, NA, 1.84578349226819, -2.17212862641572, -0.548751753048712, 
>   2.42407222784798, 1.98051589623148, 0.857017231589848, 1.02923101633178, 
>   0.603889368418457, -0.155950277329299, -1.34170207835036, -3.12632714628269, 
>   3.17556103654373, 2.20650266094645, -5.13428281112186, -0.921178268637226, 
>   -2.38181625620856, 0.160972414602853, 1.77091538996229, 4.63247625224926, 
>   -1.86579167976827, -4.69436622845745, 1.63801459948559, -2.43515279935704, 
>   NA, NA, -3.78670320087694, NA, -0.288033414912556, NA, NA, 0.0313451485705829, 
>   0.966671153586328, -1.45301303679307, 0.865396954575461, -1.04732750646681, 
>   -1.13862805823273, -3.33182170877955, -0.716789934481586, -1.46422431089161, 
>   1.80608017491006, -0.819565581598858, -3.31489269127239, 2.30213502005916, 
>   -1.19546412608738, 1.69987803022498, -1.50379312132888, 1.12150667071641, 
>   3.29476953236869, -0.174091501660731, 0.0355055954410258, 1.68302476193471, 
>   -0.933232270264013, -1.20837727976455, -5.00113669120977, 0.549514565656909, 
>   -1.22088165343573, -4.9131413352054, 0.249406010650101, -0.308297840121518, 
>   NA, 2.04846718184171, 0.560020743571995, -0.463120853229649, 
>   1.40062718046321, -3.79755640951251, -1.88533639543057, 1.57110593873126, 
>   -0.0299794333846566, 1.22247764726521, NA, -2.03497022023155, 
>   -0.407010083622181, -2.37498324523997, NA, -0.349381507825823, 
>   -3.11946075987499, NA, -2.76573219788431, 3.29139667042278, 2.21696800111447, 
>   -0.086332960380396, 0.836753244947099, -1.30865978206261, NA, 
>   -0.192919803126557, -5.35233490542491, -1.18731608332232, -3.69045479061667, 
>   -1.57841486746488, 1.18664265800922, -2.19679997569897, -2.0452403212891, 
>   NA, -1.45283826875268, NA, 4.56092709451823, -1.33156364802532, 
>   -4.39414824444583, -3.50663975811275, -0.994204002807067, 0.465461528013715, 
>   0.449957137212169, NA, -2.20473150634823, -2.43893778416633, 
>   -0.21859079543478, -2.49654949099443, -0.101281326767697, -1.83129379417679, 
>   -0.240462905250426, -1.0882958290627, -1.39034392349669, -1.14066661465865, 
>   3.78358608669209, 1.02135372275077, -0.740754000333138, NA, NA, 
>   NA, -0.256965993799418, -2.49360159097253, -2.67415175736433, 
>   -1.75805187150358, NA, NA, NA, 2.56779851815765, -1.43656049387778, 
>   2.29452798322785, 0.862942019010368, 2.09421244256466, -2.00177427820928, 
>   1.38403406309234, 0.740884397517659, 0.521458258281686, NA, NA, 
>   3.45339851475839, NA, -3.26999440857194, 3.22431706477516, 1.12146738985331, 
>   NA, NA, -3.35074461633528, -4.77834384105443, 0.861820227100293, 
>   -1.2056462223418, NA, -0.764953366530192, 2.15999357109029, -3.15904866930723, 
>   -2.02972340363139, 1.59312313935804, -0.690697193933604, -2.29058736067177, 
>   -5.13147313144091, 1.07236945986908, 0.108280351864803, -1.52505465628159, 
>   -1.88392986532853, -0.913313498148003, 3.45065659884515, -1.51081560834924, 
>   NA, 3.00567498412257, NA, 2.29831624955477, -2.39939672938326, 
>   NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -5.3996538732268, -1.42752873210144, 
>   0.0724852922370845, -0.0705972311145999, -1.61242654109663, 1.29582434107304, 
>   1.25077987465511, -5.98015252408187, -3.61932820726323, -1.07781775258866, 
>   0.286505399786564, -1.56602611718645, 0.399192492042174, 1.85548824455123, 
>   NA, -0.327392012404141, -1.97227490719439, NA, NA, -3.35557605502864, 
>   -3.290672107048, NA, 3.48660286422453, -2.86599190336319, -0.581371472493803, 
>   -2.4331708832036, -2.51410746360557, 0.288914981358372, -0.505196655524221, 
>   1.05716585109166, NA, 0.989822924708553, NA, 0.0225311655108685, 
>   1.62443349472587, -2.10875387227572, -0.587500068529866, NA, 
>   0.425562050427503, 1.22298892433114, -0.927706126888752, -0.409816745039093, 
>   -4.06011308919161, -1.03787150354729, -0.526565521964921, 1.80298858884609, 
>   -0.448432216080462, -3.45358148541365, -2.91502694941587, -0.991517726403897, 
>   3.4514878901496, NA, -1.12635167429918, NA, -1.50038036462404, 
>   2.32725535516867, 0.111782581861886, 0.470383741015466, -0.031317322019304, 
>   -0.718043104468153, -1.12920706646041, NA, 2.01061929939003, 
>   3.17413595098028, NA, 0.190603542356822, -2.22133728253356, -1.06894473164686, 
>   -0.4330706698996, 1.01987682109617, -2.03059414210894, -1.7628873247019, 
>   -2.53482602530358, -1.21416018667071, -3.67031160485705, -1.52082991320074, 
>   1.02860643265223, 0.500315605421826, -0.716811146495161, NA, 
>   -0.195815384833931, -0.493307414686167, 3.23812969301253, NA, 
>   -2.09109040458043, -3.1164773497449, -1.6343505259607, 0.379609686590297, 
>   -0.0343891823066718, 1.10485260681212, -1.13046916214953, -0.69700197840047, 
>   -5.4193074181233, NA, NA, -4.42064283033986, NA, 1.3717981277516, 
>   0.727970491803614, -0.105635233546526, -2.39685477369571, 5.1151037437021, 
>   -1.83992182746077, NA, -1.40244592017941, NA, 0.486864923336782, 
>   2.60269396800354, -3.362465559503, NA, -3.98399191993587, NA, 
>   -1.4572757861452, -1.19771254081594, -3.95432863178781, 3.21854033879276, 
>   NA, NA, 1.80796548853591, NA, -4.04344709825764, 2.05959593320529, 
>   -0.161804833493671, -0.0552164788513592, NA, -2.86741460844131, 
>   0.31984524711282, NA, NA, 4.74172559718353, 0.165786351005475, 
>   -4.36875963238208, -2.31924247294842, -0.935833349775849, NA, 
>   -3.28217665426608, 1.32131433363562, 1.71193300136779, -0.306511172657601, 
>   -3.558816156159, -1.55714569371858, NA, 1.18540625153828, -4.1986425447059, 
>   4.05642691202438, -3.75551752685627, NA, 1.39774357580828, -7.41748774382377, 
>   0.490138847007415, -1.32879211731965, 0.529098504821919, -0.798177526937817, 
>   -0.845196892300538, -2.53754126606442, -2.63918687041961, NA, 
>   NA, 3.90070676740233, -1.36316117657554), func.cat = c("5,11,22", 
>   "5,22", "5,9,22", "1,9,28", "5,11,22", "5,8,22", "4", "4,9", 
>   "5,9,25", "4,9", "4,9", "4,9,29", "7,15,18", "6,11,21,22,28,29,30", 
>   "6,11,21,28,30", "4,9,23", "4,9", "6,9,30", "6,9,30", "6,9,30", 
>   "1,9,28", "6,9", "6,9,21", "3,9,23", "1,9", "1,9", "1,9", "1", 
>   "1,9", "1,9", "9", "7,9,18", "2,9,19,27", "1,9,28", "2,9,19,27", 
>   "1,9", "4,9", "1,9,21", "4,9", "4,9", "5,11,20", "6,21", "6,9,21", 
>   "7,9,13", "2,9,28", "7,9", "1,9,21", "4,9", "1,9", "4,8,9,23", 
>   "4,9,29", "1,9,28", "5,20", "5,22", "5", "5,20", "1", "5,11,22", 
>   "1,9", "1,11", "1,9", "7,9,17", "7,9,13", "3,4,8,9", "3,9,28", 
>   "7,9", "6,21", "7,9,19,27,28", "7,9,15", "7,9,15", "5,9,22", 
>   "4,9", "4,9,32", "1,27", "7,9,15", "4,9", "7,9,28", "1,1,6,21", 
>   "1", "1,9", "1,9", "6,9", "7,9,13", "7,9,13,26", "7,9,13", "7,11,13", 
>   "7,11,13,26", "7,13", "2", "7,27,28", "4,9,29", "7,9,16", "4,9,26", 
>   "4,29", "9", "9", "", "7,9,27", "2,9,10", "2,9,10,19,27", "1,9,10", 
>   "2,9,10,27", "4,11,29", "4,9,26", "1,9,30", "5,9,20", "1,28", 
>   "4,9,26", "1,9", "8", "4,9,28", "7,9,19", "4,11,17,23", "4,9,17", 
>   "4,9,15", "4,9,28", "4,9,29", "6,9,21", "7,11,15,18", "2,19,27", 
>   "5,20", "1,9", "1,9", "1,9", "", "7,25", "3,9", "3,11,17", "4,9", 
>   "2,9,28,33", "7,9,19", "2,9,19", "7,9,13", "7,9", "3,9,28", "6,9,21", 
>   "7,9,27", "7,9", "1,9", "7,9,17,23", "1,9", "1,9,28", "1,9,22", 
>   "4,9,26", "6,9,21", "2,9,27", "2,9,27", "7,9,13", "7,9,19,27,28", 
>   "7,9,13,28", "1", "9", "9", "6,30", "2,9,19", "7,13", "7,9,13", 
>   "1,7,9", "1", "6,9,21", "9", "9", "7,13,33", "7,9,13", "1,9,28", 
>   "1,19", "6,9,21", "2,9,19,27", "3", "3,9", "3,9,10,27", "3,9,10,27", 
>   "3,9,10,27", "3,27", "4,9,10,27", "3,9,27", "4,9,10", "4,9,10", 
>   "1,9", "4,9", "4,9", "4,29", "1,9,28", "5,9,21", "7,9,19", "1,9", 
>   "1,9", "3,7", "7,9,28", "4,9", "7,11", "1,9,29", "4,9,17", "1,4,9,29", 
>   "4", "1,9", "4,9,32", "6,9,21,30", "6,9", "7,9,13", "7,9,25", 
>   "4,10", "4,9", "1,9", "4,9,28", "4", "4,9,10,29", "4,11,28", 
>   "4,9,28", "1,9", "7,11,28", "1,9", "1,9", "7,13", "6,9,18", "7,9,13", 
>   "2,9,19,27", "2,9,19", "7,9,10,19", "7,9,19", "4,8,10,28", "4,9", 
>   "7,9,19", "2", "2,19", "7,13", "7,11,27,28", "4,23", "4,11", 
>   "4,11", "7,11,19", "4,9,28", "2,9,28", "2,9,19", "6,9,21", "5,9,16", 
>   "7,13", "4,9", "4", "4,4,11", "4,9", "6,9,21", "3,9", "3,9,28", 
>   "7,9,19", "2,9,19,27,28,33", "2,9,19", "2,19", "7,9,28", "4,9", 
>   "7,13", "7,13", "7,9,10", "1,9", "3,9,25", "7,9,13", "7,9,26,28", 
>   "7,9,18", "7,9,18", "9", "1,9", "1,9", "1,9,29", "6,9,18,21,30", 
>   "4,9,26", "3,9", "1,9", "1,9", "4,9,26", "7,9,15,27", "4,9,26", 
>   "1,9,14", "1,9,22", "2,9,19,27", "2,9,19", "1,9", "6,9,21", "1,9,15", 
>   "6", "1,9,29", "3,3,9", "8", "8", "8", "2,9,27", "4,11,25", "4,11", 
>   "4,11", "11", "11", "4", "4,9,29", "4,11", "4,11", "7,11,25", 
>   "4,11", "1,9", "7,9,28", "1,9,29", "7,9,26", "9", "1,9", "1,9", 
>   "3,9", "3,9,28", "6,9,21", "7,9,19,27,28", "9", "9,24", "7,9,13", 
>   "1,9", "4,19", "4,29", "1,9", "1,11", "1,11,25", "1,9", "4,9", 
>   "7,9,17", "7,9,27", "7,9,13", "4,9,26", "7,9,25", "4,9", "7,9,16", 
>   "7,9,23", "1,9,29", "6,9,21,26", "9", "9,10", "7,27", "6,9,21", 
>   "1,9", "1,9,21", "7,9,28", "1,9", "1,9", "7,11,23", "11", "9", 
>   "7,11,15", "7,11,13", "6,21,30", "1,9", "4,9", "4,9,28", "4,28", 
>   "4,9", "1,9,28", "4,9,15", "4,11", "6,9", "1,9", "3,11,25", "3,11,25", 
>   "3,11,25", "3,9,21", "9", "24", "1,9,27", "7,11", "1", "4,9,28", 
>   "1,9", "4,9", "4,9,26", "7,17", "4,29", "1,9,17", "1,9,29", "1,9", 
>   "1,9,28", "7,9,29", "7,28", "1,9,28", "1,11,25", "7,9,13", "7,13", 
>   "7,9", "1,9,25", "6,9,21", "1", "4,9,29", "7,9,20", "1,9", "7,9,16", 
>   "4,11", "3,11,25", "7,9,13,18", "6,9,21,28,30", "1,9", "8,9", 
>   "7,9,16", "1,9,26", "7,9,15", "7,9,13", "9", "4,9", "1,9", "1,9", 
>   "1,9", "4", "4,11,32", "2,11,19", "4,9", "4,9,28", "4,9", "2,11,19,27", 
>   "2,9,27,33", "1,9,28", "7,9,13", "7,13,28", "7,9,13", "6,11,21,28,30", 
>   "4,11,15,30", "4,11", "5,9,22,28", "7,10,18", "7,11,15", "7,11,18", 
>   "7,11,18", "4,9,28", "4,9", "4,9", "1,9,28", "7,11,18", "7,11", 
>   "1,9", "4,11,26", "4", "5,10,22", "7,9", "5,11", "1,11", "4,9", 
>   "3,9", "1,9,29", "1,9,28", "4,9", "2,19", "2,9,19", "7,9,18", 
>   "7,9,19,27,28", "3,11,25", "1,9", "9", "1,9", "5,9", "5,9,21", 
>   "4,9,29", "2,9,23", "1,9", "1,28", "4,11,28", "4,9", "6,9,21", 
>   "9", "1,9", "1,9", "3", "2,3,3,9,19", "7,9,15", "7,9,13", "1,9", 
>   "1", "4,9", "7,11,13", "4,9", "1,9,29", "6,21,28", "1,9,19", 
>   "7,13", "2,9,19", "2,9,23,33", "1,18", "1,2,9,10,18,23,33", "1,9", 
>   "6,9,21", "4,9,29", "6,9,21", "4,9", "4,9", "4,9", "7,9,16", 
>   "4,11", "7,9,28", "1,9", "4,9", "4,9,29", "7,9,28", "6,9,17,21", 
>   "7,23", "1,9", "4,28", "7,17", "6,9,10", "6,9", "1", "1,7,9,15", 
>   "1,9")), .Names = c("BHTD", "BHNS", "func.cat"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
>   500L))

Comment: How about defining `cat` with multiple levels? You don't have to do it with `ifelse`. Just define the variable, then assign numeric values for each condition that holds. You can convert it to factor afterwards and use it in `ggplot`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion SimonG. Can you please give me an example of how you would code that - I'm afraid I have not idea how to define cat with multiple levels.

Comment: I just realize I misunderstood your question. I will post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here's a slightly different approach, using the first ten rows of your `dat`.

```
dat$cat <- strsplit(dat$func.cat,",")
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat) + 
  geom_point(aes(x=BHTD,y=BHNS,color=sapply(cat,function(cat) "4" %in% cat)),
             size=3)+
  scale_color_discrete("Fun.Cat=4")
```

[image]

This code creates a column, `$cat` as a list of vectors, each containing all the functional categories for the gene represented in that row. Using

```
color=sapply(cat,function(cat) "4" %in% cat)
```

tests each element of `cat` (each row of `dat`). If the vector in that row contains "4", `color=TRUE`. This may have the slight advantage that you don't have to `grep` the whole table for each category you want to highlight.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for - this will prove useful in future endeavors as well!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you mean. I use a for-loop and `grep` to create the category that is used in `ggplot`. As I understood it, you want the match one substring of `func.cat` per iteration (e.g., `"1"`).

I created a minimal example based on yours:

```
library(ggplot2)

c1 <- c("1","2","2") 
c2 <- c("2","","3") 
dat <- data.frame(BHNS=1:3,BHTD=1:3,func.cat=paste(c1,c2,sep=",")) 

for(ii in c("1","3")){ 
  dat$new.cat <- 0  
  dat <- within(dat,{ 
    new.cat[grep(gsub("i",ii,"^i$|^i,|,i$|,i,"),func.cat)] <- 1
  }) 

  p1 <- ggplot(dat, aes(x=BHNS, y=BHTD)) + 
    geom_point(aes(colour = factor(new.cat))) 

  png(file=paste("plot_",ii,".png",sep="")) 
  print(p1) 
  dev.off()    
}
```

Hope this helps.

Cheers!

EDIT: Updated the call to `grep` to not match unwanted categories.

Comment: this ALMOST works - the problem with using grep is that I have functional categories 1-34 so if I grep "4" I will also pick-up "14", "24", and "34". Is there an alternative to grep that will match the character/factor? Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Good point! I updated the `grep` call assuming `func.cat` either contains just the number or comma-separated entries otherwise.